# siunitx and summary statistics below table - separate alignment block possible?

Tags: tables, siunitx

I am using `siunitx` to format tables as it is very handy with aligning, rounding etc. However, I typically have summary statistics in a separate part below the table. Since these often only contain integer values, aligning them at the decimal point as well takes up too much space and looks odd. Simply centering them with `{}` is the obvious way but not too appealing as well.

So far, I have used `\multicolumn{1}{r}{}`, and it sort of looked alright. However, I just realized that I get a lot of overfull boxes when compiling since I did not account for the significance markers as I omitted setting `table-space-post`. If I do so, the summary statistics are moved too far to the right. (I actually prefer the more dense look without setting `table-space-post`. For some reason it looks less crammed in my document than in the minimal example below, but the warnings are annoying.)

What would be a good solution to get a nicely aligned and centered block of summary statistics at the bottom of the table? Is it possible to define distinct alignment blocks? Even better, as decimal values *may* occur as well, a simple right aligned block which is centered overall would suffice.

A minimal working example is provided below, just remove the comment before `table-space-post` to see the difference. I realize I am pretty anal about typesetting tables.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}


\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    detect-mode,
    %locale                  = US,
    input-decimal-markers   = {.},
    output-decimal-marker   = {.},
    input-ignore            = {,},
    group-digits            = true,
    %group-separator         = {,},
    %group-separator         = {},
    tight-spacing           = true,
    input-signs             = ,
    input-symbols           = ,
    input-open-uncertainty  = ,
    input-close-uncertainty = ,
    table-align-text-pre    = false,
    round-mode              = places,
    round-precision         = 3,
    table-space-text-pre    = (,
    table-space-text-post   = ),
}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{some title} 
    \label{tab:label} 
            \begin{tabular}{l*{3}{S[table-number-alignment=center,%
                                    %table-space-text-post={***},
                                    table-figures-integer=1,%
                                    table-figures-decimal=3]}}
\toprule \addlinespace[1em]
                        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Full sample} \\ \cmidrule(lr{.75em}){2-4} 
                        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}                         \\
     \midrule\\
     row1               & 1.322***                        & 1.322***                  & 1.236***                                        \\
                        & (0.088)                         & (0.088)                   & (0.075)                                         \\
     row2               & 1.085                           & 1.090                     & 1.112                                           \\
                        & (0.091)                         & (0.091)                   & (0.092)                                         \\
     row3               & 0.856*                          & 0.855*                    & 0.860*                                          \\
                        & (0.076)                         & (0.076)                   & (0.076)                                         \\
     row4               &                                 & 0.692***                  & 0.733***                                        \\
                        &                                 & (0.075)                   & (0.080)                                         \\
     row5               &                                 & 0.971                     & 0.970                                           \\
                        &                                 & (0.092)                   & (0.091)                                         \\
     \midrule\\
     Other controls     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-}           & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-}     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\checkmark}                  \\
     N municipalities   & \multicolumn{1}{r}{2,337}       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{2,338} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{2,338}                       \\
     N individuals      & \multicolumn{1}{r}{5,653}       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{5,994} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{5,994}                       \\
     N failures         & \multicolumn{1}{r}{197}         & \multicolumn{1}{r}{232}   & \multicolumn{1}{r}{232}                         \\
     more summary stats & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1,713}       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1,713} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1,713}                       \\
\bottomrule 
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Comment: You can change the alignment of "not-parse"-columns with the option table-text-alignment=right

Comment: That is identical to using `\multicolumn{1}{r}{}`, albeit more concise. I want a right-aligned centered block. Right alignment  at the last decimal of the upper part, ignoring the significance symbol. A completely new centered decimal aligned integer-only block would also be ok.

Comment: I would then probably use \rlap{***} for the significance symbols so that they take no place and enlarge the intercolumn space.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer care to answer?